# Action Creator - can you explain?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
const createRefDoneAction: (widget: widget[]) => WidgetAction = 
(widgets: widget[]) => ({
    type: actionTypes.REFRESH_WIDGET_DONE,
    widgets,
})
```

can you please explain why there are 2 brackets with parameters passed in (i.e. 'widget: widget[]' and 'widgets: widget[]' and 2 return values (i.e. 'WidgetAction' and '{type: ..., widgets,}?

trying to get an idea as to what is going on 'exactly' with this code. I have used React before but not with typescript.

Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It describe types for arguments and returning value. Take a look into [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#typing-the-function)

1. `const createRefDoneAction` declares constant of a name
2. then `: (widget: widget[]) => WidgetAction` describes this constant to be a type of function that takes single argument of array with variables of type `widget` and returns back value with type of `WidgetAction`
3. then function's body comes that is not related to TypeScript syntax but [utilizes ES6 arrow function](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html) syntax:

   ```
   = 
   (widgets: widget[]) => ({
       type: actionTypes.REFRESH_WIDGET_DONE,
       widgets,
   })
   ```

Comment: why is it the code is not like this?:

const createRefDoneAction: (widgets: widget[]) => WidgetAction => 
({
    type: actionTypes.REFRESH_WIDGET_DONE,
    widgets,
})

Comment: @quinton because after wiping/hiding type declaration it would become `const createRefDoneAction => ({ type: actionTypes.REFRESH_WIDGET_DONE, widgets, })` that has invalid syntax